# Sha 1 hashes and their length with the bit torrent protocol (magnets)?

Tags: php, hash, sha1, packed

I am scraping websites for information and it involves getting sha1 hashes of magnet links.

I get all the magnet links with a simple `preg_match_all` but in my results I am getting weird results, I understand that a magnet hash in its hexadecimal form is 40 characters long, but I am also getting results that return strings that are 32 characters long that contain other non hexadecimal values.

Two examples from my results, firstly a normal 40 hexadecimal hash within a magnet link,

```
array
    0 => string 'F5AD2D170C033736FD987106F04C3ABD6DF41D14' (length=40)
```

And the other weird results that I do not understand where the hash is a 32 non hexadecimal value,

```
array
    0 => string 'VPR33QQM3L6BFU5FGOZXMBNORAFFSZWW' (length=32)
```

Has the hash been packed in some way? I know it is not done with `pack('H*', $hash)` as that returns the binary of the hash? The magnet links do work as I have tested them.

More so you can see these hashes in use at this website

http://eztv.it

By hovering over the magnet links and looking a the magnet hash.

Thanks

Comment: That's other magnet information, your regex (which is a terrible way to parse an html page) must also be grabbing tracker information.

Comment: @AlexLunix I am not on about the other information, I am on about the hash which is in the second example with a length of 32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashes in magnet links can be encoded using [Base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32). In your example,

```
VPR33QQM3L6BFU5FGOZXMBNORAFFSZWW
```

turns into

```
ABE3BDC20CDAFC12D3A533B37605AE880A5966D6
```

which is a valid SHA-1 hash.

Comment: Thank you just what I was after, :)

Comment: The php website will not load, any idea how I can convert these in php to the original hexadecimal format? Thanks

Comment: @Griff: As far as I know PHP has no built in way to decode base32. There are libraries that can do that though

Answer (score 1):

Basically its not a valid torrent info hash, only sha1 (40 bytes) are valid, a torrent client or bencode script would fail if you passed that as a torrent hash.

It seems its related to:

`http://eztv.it/magnet:?xt=urn:btih:VPR33QQM3L6BFU5FGOZXMBNORAFFSZWW`
Which is noting.

Comment: I you should also add `zoink.it` to your cache search when doing hash to torrent file :) I like your script :)! When using this link within u torrent though it does start downloading it?